# How to use Symbol.isConcatSpreadable in TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

The code I am trying to run is like below:

```
const colorArray = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow']
const numberArray = ['1', '2', '3']
console.log(colorArray.concat(numberArray))
numberArray[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = false // Line with error
console.log(colorArray.concat(numberArray))
```

When I use VSCode for editing on the fourth line it gives an error (The code works though)

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

How can I change this code so that I get rid of this index type error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know that Typescript doesn't allow you to set `index` as `symbol` type (seems only `string` | `number` are allowed). So in order to make it work, you might cast `symbol` -> `any` as workaround solution:

```js
const colorArray: Array<string | boolean> = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow']
const numberArray: Array<string | boolean> = ['1', '2', '3']
console.log(colorArray.concat(numberArray))
numberArray[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable as any] = false // Line with error
console.log(colorArray.concat(numberArray))
```

Comment: After a lot of digging I see that there is no way to convert symbol to accepted index type. So the only way is to apply your solution.